# command at boot, before another script

Tags: boot, shell-script, solaris

This should be an easy question, but as a solaris novice, I'm stuck.
I have to launch a change MAC address command at boot (i.e. ifconfig bge0 ether).
If I do this at terminal, everything goes smooth.
where should I put this little command to make it run at boot?
I already know about init.d directory and symlinks at rcX.d directories, but I don't know what to put in it, as I never made a script.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can see an /etc/init.d/rc.local you can put it there, if not then go to:

> cd /etc/init.d/rc3.d

Then create a simple file named : S99ether for example

In it:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ifconfig bge0 ether
```

Check to make sure that ifconfig is under /sbin.  To check: type ifconfig

Then

> chmod 755 S99ether

Try to run S99ether by hand if should execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it's Solaris 10 or earlier, you should be able to just add your `ether mac` to the entry in /etc/hostname.bge0.

ie:

`myserver [8] more /etc/hostname.bge0
myserver ether <the_mac_you_want>`